# Problems with PHP YAML within Travis CI

Tags: php, yaml, pecl, travis-ci

Edit: I believe the problem is that YAML doesn't work on 5.4/5.5.

I have a library that is setup in Travis CI and that uses the PHP YAML PECL extension. However, I am unable to get the YAML extension to work in Travis & PHP 5.4, and I'm curious if anyone else has? No amount of Googling has solved my problem.

Here is the output of Travis:

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch="master" git://github.com/titon/IO.git titon/IO

Cloning into 'titon/IO'...

remote: Counting objects: 531, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (256/256), done.

remote: Total 531 (delta 267), reused 460 (delta 196)

Receiving objects: 100% (531/531), 79.41 KiB, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (267/267), done.

$ cd titon/IO
git.2

$ git checkout -qf 3940a6673413da224eeaaebbc6a98167e4feda38

$ phpenv global 5.4

$ php --version

PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2013 06:18:12)

Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
before_script.1

$ sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

libyaml-dev is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ pecl install yaml

downloading yaml-1.1.0.tgz ...

Starting to download yaml-1.1.0.tgz (35,916 bytes)

..........done: 35,916 bytes

9 source files, building

WARNING: php_bin /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.13/bin/php appears to have a prefix ., but config variable php_prefix does not match

WARNING: php_bin /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.13/bin/php appears to have a suffix env/versions/5.4.13/bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match

running: phpize

Configuring for:

PHP Api Version: 20100412

Zend Module Api No: 20100525

Zend Extension Api No: 220100525

Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation [autodetect] : (Waits until it times out)
```

The travis.yml in question: https://github.com/titon/IO/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automating PECL installs is a problem that is encountered not just on Travis CI. In this case, a pseudo-`expect` script can be created by sending a cariage return into the stdin of the PECL installer which will in turn pass it on to the configure script that is prompting for input:

```
printf "\n" | pecl install yaml
```

A working version of your .travis.yml would then look something like:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5

before_script:
  - printf "\n" | pecl install yaml-beta
  - echo "extension=yaml.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
  - composer install --dev

notifications:
  email: false
```

Comment: I noticed your testing on Github, thanks a lot for the help! I tried porting it over to my project but continue to get permission denied errors when it tries to run the bash script. Not sure what to do from here. https://github.com/titon/IO

Comment: @MilesJohnson Your bin/travis-yaml.sh doesn't have the execute bit set in its file permissions. You need to `chmod a+x bin/travis-yaml.sh; git add .; git commit` so that the file is marked as executable when Travis clones the repo.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but I'm on windows so it doesn't ever work. I'll have to try it on another comp.

Comment: On windows (or unix) you can set permissions using git directly : `git update-index --chmod=+x bin/travis-yaml.sh; git commit`

Comment: You don't need to append to php.ini in `before_script`. The extension is enabled automatically, as can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/shadiakiki1986/fatca-ides-php/builds/137704548#L295)

Answer (score 2):

**.travis.ci**

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - 5.6

sudo:
  false

before_install:
  - pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
  - (CFLAGS="-O1 -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing"; pecl install yaml < /dev/null &)

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libyaml-dev
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need for the `addons` section. [My build](https://travis-ci.org/shadiakiki1986/fatca-ides-php/builds/137704548#L203) finds the `yaml` dev files without it.