# How to install a custom PHP extension on Travis (OAuth)

Tags: php, oauth, travis-ci

I'd like to install the [PHP extension `OAuth`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) in my build environment on Travis.

I've tried these two configuration in `.travis.yml` file:
COnfiguration 1 (using `before_script`):

```
language: php

matrix:
    include:
        - php: 5.3
        - php: 5.4
        - php: 5.5
        - php: 5.6
        - php: 7.0
        - php: hhvm

cache:
    directories:
        - $HOME/.composer/cache

install:
    - travis_retry composer update ${COMPOSER_FLAGS} --no-interaction

script:
    - phpunit --verbose --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml
    - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini || return 0

before_script:
    - pecl install oauth
```

Configuration 2 (using `install`):

```
language: php

matrix:
    include:
        - php: 5.3
        - php: 5.4
        - php: 5.5
        - php: 5.6
        - php: 7.0
        - php: hhvm

cache:
    directories:
        - $HOME/.composer/cache

install:
    - travis_retry composer update ${COMPOSER_FLAGS} --no-interaction
    - pecl install oauth

script:
    - phpunit --verbose --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml
    - phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini || return 0
```

The [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Installing-additional-PHP-extensions) isn't clear about where to put the commands to install custom PHP extensions (or maybe I've not understood it, it's possible!).

Anyway, can someone help me configure Travis to install `OAuth` PHP extension? Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Per [Problems with PHP YAML within Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995009/problems-with-php-yaml-within-travis-ci?rq=1) it looks like the `pecl install` goes in the `before_script` section.

Per my own testing here https://travis-ci.org/davidjeddy/no-code/jobs/345523220 it appears that does the trick.